Chaining flycheck tide and eslint checkers
I use tide-mode and flycheck for editing TypeScript files. flycheck currently executes the javascript-tide checker fine and I can correctly see my TypeScript errors. But I would really like to see errors from eslint too.
My flycheck-verify-setup says:
Syntax checkers for buffer example.ts in typescript-mode:

First checker to run:

  typescript-tide
    - may enable:        yes
    - may run:           t
    - Typescript server: running
    - Tide mode:         enabled

Checkers that could run if selected:

  javascript-eslint  select
    - may enable:  yes
    - executable:  Found at /home/me/project/node_modules/.bin/eslint
    - config file: found

  typescript-tslint  select
    - may enable:         yes
    - executable:         Found at /home/me/.npm-packages/bin/tslint
    - configuration file: Not found

Flycheck Mode is enabled.  Use C-u C-c ! x to enable disabled checkers.

--------------------

Flycheck version: 35.0-snapshot
Emacs version:    29.4
System:           x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Window system:    x

From this buffer, I can hit select against javascript-eslint and it will show me the eslint errors correctly. But I don't understand how to see both tide and eslint errors.
I understand that flycheck has a checker "chaining" feature and I have the following in my ~/.emacs:
(flycheck-add-next-checker 'javascript-eslint 'javascript-tide)

I'm assuming this must be wrong somehow but I don't know what it's supposed to be.

The name of the tide checker was wrong in my config. The correct config is:
(flycheck-add-next-checker 'typescript-tide 'javascript-eslint)

So the checker is called typescript-tide (not javascript-tide as I originally had).
Embarrassingly, it was actually staring me in the face. The flycheck-verify-setup buffer very clearly says that the checker is called typescript-tide.
